# How to send Firebase Push Notifications from the device itself?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Hi I need help for my Android App. 
I work with Firebase Push notification and unfortunately found only one way to send push notifications - from the website itself.

i like to create a function that u can enter title and content to send push notifications to all of my app users.

Goal: an admin screen.
Enter Title: this is an edittext with title
Enter Content: this is an edittext with content 
Send button - this will send the notification to all of the app users.

is there a way to do so?
Thank you!

Comment: There is no secure way to send messages to devices with just FCM from the device itself. Sending a message **to** a device requires that you specify the FCM server key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. The typical flow is that your app calls a Cloud Function, or writes to a database which triggers a Cloud Function. The Cloud Function then checks if the content is OK, and calls the FCM API to send the message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen why isn't there a secure API for it then? Using Cloud Functions just for that seems like an overkill tbh...

Comment: If you'd like that feature to be added (I definitly would love to see it), the best you can do is to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 0):

You can send push notification from device using POST request to this URL:

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

You'll need to provide these headers:

```
Authorization: key="Firebase server key"
Content-Type: application/json
```

And the request body with Notification message and other additional info:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/topic_name",
  "data": {
    "title": "Notification title",
     "message": "Notification message",
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2" //additional data you want to pass
  }
}
```

You can find more info in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/mindorks/send-device-to-device-push-notification-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-without-using-external-769476c79ffd).

Comment: Doing this from the device itself means that you're including the FCM server key into the app that you send to your users. That is a *security risk*, as a malicious who gets your app can now get that key and use it to send any message they want to all users of the app.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen - In this person’s case - to build an admin screen - could the risk not be mitigated by having the app retrieve the FCM server key from the Firestore database *only* for admin users?  That way the key is not compiled into the app - and it is protected by the Firestore database rules.

Comment: Hmm,... interesting idea Jim.